# Index positioning with a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To learn, I want to print out which element is where an array:

```
a = [1,2,3]

a.each_with_index do |element, index|
  print "#{element} is at position #{index}"
end
```

This works but my aim is to wrap it in a method. I tried like this:

```
def addValue(a)
a.each_with_index do |element, index|
  print "#{element} is at position #{index}"
end
```

But this gives me a syntax error.

Any thoughts on how I should do this?

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit, but left the code formatting in your second example much as it was, to emphasize a point: Keep your code correctly indented and you'll find it helps identify missing terminators. Any decent source-code editor will help you to maintain indentation so if you're not using one then start. It'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close your method. It should be:

```
def addValue(a)
  a.each_with_index do |element, index|
    print "#{element} is at position #{index}"
  end
end
```

Make sure always to indent your code properly to prevent this kind of errors.